# DS 1307 power issue

Tags: rtc

My DS1307 stops functioning when switching the relays. It looks like a power fluctuation problem. I added 4.7uf capacitor in parallel with the power source too. Before adding 4.7uf cap DS1307 stopped very frequently, after adding capacitor, once in a while. But still the issue is not resolved. Can anyone help me on this?

Comment: show us a schematic please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A relay draws some current when switched, so it might be your power supply just can't handle that and starts behaving weird (unstable or too low voltage).

As you wrote, 4.7uF resolved the problem partially - that points to an unstable power supply. Try adding a capacitor with a higher capacity to make it more stable.

If you have an oscilloscope, you can use it to check how stable exactly your power supply is.

Comment: Sure. I will add more capacitance and check.

Comment: Circuit functioning fine. I replaced 4.7uf with 22uf capacitor. DS1307 has not stopped till now. so far so good. Thank you.

Comment: @ShamAV good news; happy to help.

Answer (score 1):

If adding a capacitor even as small as 4.7uF worked to prevent most issues, then surely adding twice as much or even a 47uF bulk capacitor for good measure, would work!

Most like this feature mentioned on the Maxim DS1307 product page: "The DS1307 has a built-in power-sense circuit that detects power failures and automatically switches to the backup supply. Timekeeping operation continues while the part operates from the backup supply."

I suspect that your relays are causing a power supply ripple/surge, dropping the input voltage at the DS1307 long enough for it to detect "power failure" and switch over to back-up supply. Do you even have a back-up supply? If not, there is the issue. Add a coin cell battery, or buffer your VCC pins for the DS1307 with MUCH more capacitance.

Comment: Yes their is coin cell backup battery. Let me increase the cap and check.

Comment: Circuit functioning fine. I replaced 4.7uf with 22uf capacitor. DS1307 has not stopped till now. so far so good. Thank you for your advice.

Comment: @ShamAV that's great news! Glad that we at the EE.SE can help you